# antd table pagination with buttons

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is it possible to configure antd `<Table/>` component to use pagination with buttons instead of dropdown while using ***showSizeChanger***

Example:

This

[image: This]

Instead of this

[image: Instead of this]

Comment: No, in this case you would need to create your own custom component and set `pagination={false}` on `Table`. Or hack away using js to convert the select into a list of buttons...

Answer (score 1):

Since version `4.17.0` in `antd` it became possible to redefine the select component. For this you need to pass the `selectComponentClass` props in the pagination config:

```
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";

const selectComponentClass = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onClick: props.onChange
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
selectComponentClass.Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5,
        border: "1px solid black",
        borderRadius: 3,
        cursor: "pointer"
      }}
      onClick={() => props.onClick(props.value)}
    >
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
};

const TableWithCustomPagination = () => {
  return (
    <Table
      columns={[]}
      pagination={{
        total: 50,
        selectComponentClass,
        showSizeChanger: true,
        position: ["bottomLeft"]
      }}
      dataSource={[]}
    />
  );
};
```

For earlier `antd` versions you would need to create your own custom component